# Is it possible to exit `podman run -t` if standard input is redirected?

Tags: tty, input, exit, pseudoterminal, podman

When I run

```
podman run -t "" alpine:3 sh
```

Everything works and is kosher, and I can exit by typing `exit`, or <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. However, if I run

```
podman run -t "" alpine:3 sh <<EOF
EOF
```

Now I can't. I realize this is presenting a heredoc means the input becomes a fifo and that STDIN get redirected, but is there no way to recover from this shy of killing it in another process?

I see this mentioned in the docs,

> NOTE: The `-t` option is incompatible with a redirection of the Podman client standard input.