# When is podman start's `-i` needed, and how does `-i` work on podman create?

Tags: stdin, podman

`podman create` has a `-i` flag, and without the terminal's STDIN doesn't get sent the program you run in the container, for example (don't run this)

```
podman run -t alpine:3 /bin/sh
```

[There is no way to exit out of that without killing it on another terminal.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/619502/3285) What you're supposed to run is,

```
# Now with -i redirecting STDIN so you can `exit`
podman run -ti alpine:3 /bin/sh
```

Now you can exit by quitting the shell. The `podman create` command also has an `-i` command, which is documented the same way,

```
-i, --interactive Keep STDIN open even if not attached
```

Even `podman start` has an `-i` command (documented the same way), but in the case of `create` ... `start` sequence, rather than a `run` it seems all the `-i`s are unnecessary. What are these supposed to do, and how are they different?

```
podman create -t alpine:3 /bin/sh # no -i option
podman start -a -l                # no -i option, terminal accepts STDIN
```

It would seem like the term should not be reading STDIN.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this one but: `podman create alpine:3 /bin/sh` will exit as there is no stdin (it looks like `-t` (pseudo tty) also provides that). If you use `-i` instead, it'll allocate a stdin and keep it ready and you can `attach` to it later (without having to use a pseudo tty).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's intended to be used like that, but this seems to work: `podman create -i alpine:3 /bin/cat` `podman start ...` `echo "hi" | podman attach ...`.

Comment: However, this doesn't seem to terminate properly after the container exits (due to the main process exiting). That may be a bug...

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need `-i` if you specify `-t`, which [is documented as](http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-create.1.html)

> When set to true Podman will allocate a pseudo-tty and attach to the standard input of the container. This can be used, for example, to run a throwaway interactive shell. The default is false.

The `-a` and `-i` options `start` can’t be used to override (cancel) `-t` or `-i` options given to `create`. They are useful when those options *weren’t* specified at `create` time. Note that `-i` has a slightly different meaning on [`create`](http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-create.1.html):

> Keep STDIN open even if not attached.

v. [`start`](http://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-start.1.html):

> Attach container’s STDIN.

In both cases, `-i` can be used without `-t` or `-a`, although it might not do anything useful (depending on what the commands running in the container expect).

Comment: So what are the options to `create` good for if they don't override `create`'s setting, and what does `-i` do in either of them?

Comment: See the update.